# How to store value for multiple iteration

Tags: matlab

Below is my code:

```
a= 10;
b= [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0;1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1;1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0;1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0;1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ];
e= [0.05 0.08 0.2 0.4];
iteration= 1;
x= zeros(1,1);

g= eye(10);
G= [g;b];

for t=1 : iteration
    s=zeros(4,1);
    offset=1;
    for u=e(1:length(e))
        F = G ;
        for i=1:15
            if(rand < u)
                F(i,:) = 0;
            end
        end
        soup=zeros(1,a);
        for k = 1 : 15
            FD = max( F(k,:)-soup, 0) ;
            if( sum(FD) == 1)
                [MaxValue Idx] = max(FD) ;
                soup(Idx) = 1 ;
            end
        end
        h =sum(soup) ;
        s(offset,:)=h;
        offset=offset+1;
    end
end
```

from this code i am getting `h=[10;10;10;8]`.afterthat i will count how many `10` in `h`. but if set iteration=5 then i only get h for last iteration.so i cannot count number of 10 from each iteration.i don't want to store all the iteration value of h rather i want store how many number of 10 in each iteration

Now I want to change the value of `“iteration”` and want to make it `1000`; For, each `“iteration”`

1. I want to count how many values of `“s”` are equal to `“a”`. Suppose, for each `“iteration”` the number of values in `“s”` that are equal to `“a”` is `“T”`(Let)
2. Then I want to divide `“T”` by length(e) for each iteration. Suppose that value for each `iteration` is `V` (Let)
3. Then I want to get the average value of `V` for total thousand `“iteration”`

Example:
Let, for `2 iteration`, the number of values in `“s”` that are equal to `“a”` is `3,2`
So,

```
 For iteration=1, V=3/length(e)=3/4=0.75
     For iteration = 2, V=2/length(e)=0.5
So,  average value of V for two iteration = (0.75+0.5) / 2 = 0.625
```

I tried for several times but unable to do so.

Matlab experts please need your help and suggestion.

Comment: It's good to include code, but yours is a bit long, the purpose is unclear, and the concrete problem is unclear. If you want iteration to be 1000, why not just `iteration = 1000;`?

Comment: @ A. Donda if i just use iteration = 1000 then i am unable to count the values which are equal to "a" for each iteration. In my program if you use iteration =2 then you will get the value of s only for second iteration. Please read the example part then the problem will be clear to you.

Comment: Well then wrap the whole stuff in another for loop. `n = 1000; for iteration = 1 : n` ... compute and store result ... `end`

Comment: @ A.Donda it is hard to follow you. Did you check before you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I get a little bit lost in your question, but here is what I think you need:

1. Find or define the variables that you want to keep after the iteration is done
2. Make sure they are indexed with the iteration, for example replace `h` everywhere by `h(iteration)`
3. After all iterations are done, evaluate your results and calculate averages

Comment: @ Dennis Jaheruddin -i am trying to clear my question.In my code iteration =1. so i am getting h=[10;10;10;8].afterthat i will count how many 10 in k. but if set iteration=5 then i only get h for last iteration.so i cannot count number of 10 from each iteration.i don't want to store all the iteration value of h rather i want store how many number of 10 in each iteration.

Comment: @user2663126 How about creating a variable `numberOfTens` and storing to it with `numberOfTens(iteration)`

Comment: @ Dennis Jaheruddin-i do so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right at the start of your loop:

```
for t=1 : iteration
    s=zeros(4,1);

    ...

    s(offset,:)=h;
    offset=offset+1;
```

This means that you reset your variable `s` in each iteration. If you move the initialization of `s` to outside the loop, things should work just fine. As it is, you appear to store only the result of the last iteration (you zeroed the previous ones out).

**EDIT** it's a little bit hard to know what the size of `h` is (it looks like a single value, but you are doing `s(offset,:) = h;` which is a bit confusing).  Anyway, if you make `s` big enough to contain all the values, and index it properly, you should be OK:

```
s = zeros( iteration, 4, 1 );

for t = 1 : iteration

  ...

  s(t, offset, :) = h;
  offset = offset + 1;
```

Now, you will have all the values of `h`, for each iteration, in `s`. Is that better?

**edit 2** you want the number of times `h` was `10` in each iteration. Put this line outside the `for t=` loop:

```
Hcount = zeros(1,iteration);
```

And this inside after you calculated `h`:

```
Hcount(t) = numel(find(h==10));
```

At the end of the ‘for`loop this will contain what you wanted - and you can check it against`s`which will have one row of`h` values for every iteration.

Comment: Did you move the initialization to outside the loop (the bit I quoted still had it inside)? What does "it's not working" mean in this case? I am not sure I know what the size of `h` is - could it be that you need an additional dimension on `s` to keep it all?

Comment: I mean if i move s outside the loop still it does not work that what i want.I am trying to make h of the function of iteration.But not sure whether it is correct or not.

Comment: @ Floris-from this code i am getting h=[10;10;10;8].afterthat i will count how many 10 in h. but if set iteration=5 then i only get h for last iteration.so i cannot count number of 10 from each iteration.i don't want to store all the iteration value of h rather i want store how many number of 10 in each iteration.

Comment: See my newest edit - I finally am beginning to understand (I think...)!